# arranging legend labels in minitab

Tags: charts, label, minitab

I want to arrange my labels shown in legend box in Minitab 17 in a way that I have my legend labels in rows instead of coloumns since I want to put my legend under my graph not beside it. I have shown the example of my desired legend box in the picture below. (please note that I have edited it with paint that you could see the desire)

[image: Click here to see the example picture.]

Thanks in advance and kind regards